# Cannot Use/Open Microsoft Access Expression Builder

Tags: ms-access, expressionbuilder

I am putting together a simply query like I have done many times before in Microsoft Access 2010. I need to use expression builder to make a calculation for one of the query fields.

BUT

When I try to open or use the expression builder it is grayed out and I cannot access it. I am not sure what I am doing to make the expression builder un-usable.

I tested making a new query, and I noticed that it starts with me being able to use the builder, but if I add additional tables to the query, or if I add some attributes etc it suddenly becomes unavailable to use.

So I tested just using MySQL code and hand writing the functions instead of using expression builder and it works fine, there is nothing wrong with the code or ability to use the code, but it won't let me write it in the expression builder, this is very annoying obviously and I would like to see if anyone knows why.